# C# Combobox selecting issue

Tags: dictionary, combobox, selection

I am stuck on the problem with Combobox selecting. First I will try to make some overview. I am getting the value of device type form accdb database it is number but I read it as string. Then I have on my form Combobox with the list of names and corresponding numbers created as Dictionary. I am trying to select corresponding item from the combobox list but for some reason it is always showing first item from the list. Even if I am getting different numbers from data

I create a public Dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> typeComboSource = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

in the OnLoad event of the form I have:

```
typeComboSource.Add("Type 0 - ION Chamber Smoke Detector [RDJ2 SPB-1]", "0");
typeComboSource.Add("Type 1 - Optical Smoke Detector [RDO-2]", "1");
typeComboSource.Add("Type 2 - Optical Smoke Detector [RDO-2-SPB-1]", "2");
typeComboSource.Add("Type 3 - Optical Smoke Detector - Intrinsically Safe Type [NID-38 FB/IS]", "3");
typeComboSource.Add("Type 4 - Optical Smoke Heat Detector [EV-PH]", "4");
typeComboSource.Add("Type 5 - Heat Detector [???]", "5");
typeComboSource.Add("Type 6 - Flame Detector [???]", "6");
typeComboSource.Add("Type 7 - Isolator [KS-2]", "7");
typeComboSource.Add("Type 8 - Isolator [KS-2K]", "8");
typeComboSource.Add("Type 9 - Manual Call Point - Non-Watertight Type [LK-2]", "9");
typeComboSource.Add("Type 10 - Manual Call Point - Drip-Proof Type [LK-2K]", "10");
typeComboSource.Add("Type 11 - Manual Call Point - Intrinsically Safe Type [BTA-LK]", "11");
DeviceTypeBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
DeviceTypeBox.ValueMember = "Value";
DeviceTypeBox.DataSource = typeComboSource.ToList();
```

When I read data from database I have this:

```
DeviceTypeBox.SelectedValue = reader["Type"].ToString();
```

I was trying with the `SelectedIndex` and other solutions from internet neither was working for me.
What is also strange I am setting `SelectedValue` as above but when I try to show it for example in MessegeBox I am getting:

> System.NullReferenceException

BTW. I have found on some pages that Combobox should have ItemsSource parameter however Visual Studio do not recognise it. It has only DataSource. Solutions are from some older version of the hmm... programming language? I am just curious.

Edited:
Here is whole code of my Reading Data function, I assume that error is somewhere in it:

```
private void ReadDataFromExcel(string dbID)
{
string strDSN = mainForm.providerData + mainForm.databaseFile + ";";
string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM DevicesList WHERE ID =" + dbID;

using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(strDSN))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM DevicesList WHERE ID = @dbID";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("dbID", dbID);
    connection.Open();
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        ZoneNoText.Text = reader["ZoneNo"].ToString();
        AddressText.Text = reader["PhysicalAddress"].ToString();
        Desc1Text.Text = reader["DescriptionText1"].ToString();
        Desc2Text.Text = reader["DescriptionText2"].ToString();

        // Here is problematic issue. I am getting System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 
        DeviceTypeBox.SelectedIndex = 3;


        PosXText.Text = reader["posX"].ToString();
        PosYText.Text = reader["posY"].ToString();
        TextPosBox.Text = reader["posText"].ToString();
        SideMapBox.Text = reader["SideViewPic"].ToString();
        SupportCardBox.Text = reader["SupportCardNo"].ToString();
        CameraNoText.Text = reader["CameraNo"].ToString();
        if(reader["DrencherSection"].ToString() != "" || reader["SprinklerSection"].ToString() != "")
        {
            if (reader["DrencherSection"].ToString() != "")
            {
                SectionTypeCheckBox.SetItemChecked(0, true);
                SectionNoText.Text = reader["DrencherSection"].ToString();
            }
            if (reader["SprinklerSection"].ToString() != "")
            {
                SectionTypeCheckBox.SetItemChecked(1, true);
                SectionNoText.Text = reader["SprinklerSection"].ToString();
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You are using WinForms.  Your key and value look backwards, but maybe you want it that way?  What information does `reader["Type"].ToString();` return?

Comment: reader returns number as a string from 0 to 11. Regarding key and value you mean which one is on first place and second place when I am adding?? If I understood your question right, Yes I want to show long text name in the list but use for code purpose numbers.

Comment: Reverse your load putting the string number key first instead: `typeComboSource.Add("7", "Type 7 - Isolator [KS-2]");`  and then switch your properties: `DeviceTypeBox.ValueMember = "Key"; DeviceTypeBox.DisplayMember = "Value";`

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to follow Your sugestion. However this doesn't help. But I did for test purpose test button and I enter code `DeviceTypeBox.SelectedValue = 3;`. When I click on the button combobox is becoming clear/empty. But when I am adding `DeviceTypeBox.SelectedIndex = 3;` seems to be working fine. When I click test button it is showing text for index no 3. Strange.

Comment: Ok I go further. I enter this code `DeviceTypeBox.SelectedIndex = 3;` into my reading function and not working. So maybe something with my function.
I cannot add here code of my reading function i comments I will add it to main post.

Comment: `SelectedIndex = 3` will select the fourth item in the list.  Try updating your post with the changes you made to your code.

Comment: Oh, and remove the `.ToList()` here: `DeviceTypeBox.DataSource = typeComboSource.ToList();`

Comment: Hi LarsTech, removing `.ToList()` gives an System.ArgumentException unfortunately I have rest in polish not English. But I will try to translate :)
"DataBinding accepts as source either IList elements and IListSource"

Comment: The only way `DeviceTypeBox.SelectedIndex = 3;` throws an out of range exception is if that ComboBox isn't loaded yet when this code runs.

Comment: Yes LarsTech, You are right. My mistake I was reading data before OnLoad event. I mean during form initialization. So that was the problem and moving function call after combobox "creation" solved the problem. Thank You for Your help LarsTech. Appreciated for Your help :)